# Will a Google Structured Data Testing Tool error for one item prevent getting a Rich Snippet for another item?

Tags: seo, google-search, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool

I have a WordPress website which, when run through the Google Structured Data Testing Tool, returns an error

> The property `logo` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `WebPage`.

Do I need to solve this issue in order for my product page aggregate rating stars to be displayed on the Google search results page?

In other words, will the `WebPage` structured data error invalidate all other structured data on the page (in this case my aggregate rating stars rich snippet)?

Note: I cannot test it out because I have yet to uncheck "Discourage search engines from indexing this site", as the website is still in development.

Comment: You seem to have two questions (should it be fixed / how can it be fixed), but the second question probably can’t be answered without seeing your code. It might make sense to focus on the first question here and head to a programming-related site (like Stack Overflow) if it’s about changing WordPress’ PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends how the WebPage and other schema are linked, and what rich snippet exactly you would like to be shown (as you seem to contradict yourself):

- If your WebPage and Product schema are separate and unlinked, then errors in the WebPage schema will not affect either the Products Rich Snippets or the Reviews Rich Snippets.
- If Product is the MainEntity of WebPage, then even if you have correct schema in both, the Products Rich Snippets will not be shown. If the Product schema within the WebPage schema is correct, the Reviews Rich Snippets will be shown though.

You can check what schema is shown using the Structured Data Testing Tool and clicking the Filter by use case dropdown.

[image]

Comment: I have fixed the question to clarify my intentions. I would like to display the aggregate rating (with stars), as seen [here](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/reviews#examples). Is it OK if I comment a link to the website for you to run through the Testing Tool?

Comment: @Beg Yes that's fine. You can always [run it through yourself](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), but I'll do it for you if you really want.